# How to switch from an interval based solution to a delay based using RxJS

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am new to typescript and RxJs and was assigned a bug where our search often fails with HTTP 404 status.
Especially when the user runs the app from remote.

The search call is made to a backend that spins off long running searches that will have to be polled until they are done. This is done by giving a X-TaskId in the header.

I found the suspicious method below and I suspect that what this method does is polling each second regardless of how long the search call takes. I.e. there is a risk for polling a search taskId that has been completed and does not exist which will give us a 404.

The return HTTP status

- 200: When search is done in which case the response body will contain the result.
- 202: The search is running and an X-TaskId header field indicates its id.
- 404: The given search taskId does not exist.

```
  performSearch(pollingInterval: number, searchCriterias: string[], search: MalSokningDto[], actor: string): void {
    this.scrollAndFocus(searchCriterias[0]);
    this.searchSubscription = this.searchService.search(search, null).subscribe(
      (initialResponse: HttpResponse<ResponseDto>) => {
        if (initialResponse.status === 202) {
          this.taskId = initialResponse.headers.get('X-TaskId');
          interval(pollingInterval)
            .pipe(
              switchMap(() => this.searchService.search(search, this.taskId)),
              filter((response: HttpResponse<ResponseDto>) => response.status === 200),
              take(1),
              timeout(30000)
            )
            .subscribe(
              (response: HttpResponse<ResponseDto>) => {
                this.loading = false;
                this.showSearchResult(searchCriterias, response.body, actor, null);
              },
              (error: Error) => {
                this.loading = false;
                this.showSearchResult(searchCriterias, null, actor, error);
              }
            );
        }
      },
      (error: Error) => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.showSearchResult(searchCriterias, null, actor, error);
      }
    );
  }
```

I have lots of question about this code.

1. How do I (In RxJS async) style switch to refactor this to adding a wait for previous call plus a delay between server calls.
2. There is redundancy in that we have two calls to searchService.search and 3 calls to showSearchResult.
3. We store a global searchSubscription (that we later may cancel) but what about all the others that are created. (Our searches may take 10-30 seconds so there will be 20-30 calls made) I guess our cancel search does not always work either.

Comment: The loading solution seems inelegant to.

Comment: So, the 200 and 404 are the same use case, right? Does that mean the search is over?

Comment: Yes 200 is a successful seach result. 404 means that you have sent a request with a taskId that does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is what I come up with for polling with a delay in between polls.

```
/**
 * Fetch search result. At first call backend will create a LongRunningTask plus return
 * a corresponding taskId. We will then poll with given taskId until we have a result.
 */
performSearchg(searchCriterias: string[], search: MalSokningDto[], actor: string): void {
    let milllisBetweenPolls: number = 1000;

    // -- Cancel any previous ongoing search. (taskId => null). --
    this.cancelSearch();

    let stopPoll: Subject<void> = new Subject();

    this.searchService.search(search, this.taskId).pipe(
      expand(_ => timer(milllisBetweenPolls).pipe(
        mergeMap(_ => this.searchService.search(search, this.taskId))
        )
      ),
      takeUntil(stopPoll)
    ).subscribe(
      (response: HttpResponse<ResponseDto>) => {
        switch (response.status) {
          case 200: {
            stopPoll.next();
            this.loading = false;
            this.showSearchResult(searchCriterias, response.body, actor, null);
            break;
          }
          case 202: {
            this.taskId = response.headers.get('X-TaskId');
            break;
          }
          default: {
            stopPoll.next();
            this.loading = false;
            this.showSearchResult(searchCriterias, null, actor, new Error(Constants.SEARCH_ERROR));
            break;
          }
        }
      },
      (error: Error) => {
        this.loading = false;
        slutaPolla.next();
        this.showSearchResult(searchCriterias, null, aktor, error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  import { Observable, Subject, timer } from 'rxjs';
  import { switchMap, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

  private refreshInterval$: Observable<any> = timer(0, 30000)
  private killTrigger: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  performSearch(pollingInterval: number, searchCriterias: string[], search: MalSokningDto[], actor: string): void {

  this.scrollAndFocus(searchCriterias[0]);
  this.searchSubscription =
    this.searchService.search(search, null)
    .subscribe(
        (initialResponse: HttpResponse < ResponseDto > ) => {
            this.refreshInterval$
                .pipe(
                    takeUntil(this.killTrigger),
                    switchMap(() => {
                            if (initialResponse.status === 202) {
                                this.taskId = initialResponse.headers.get('X-TaskId');
                                return this.searchService.search(search, this.taskId))
                        }
                    }),
        )
        .subscribe(
            (response: HttpResponse < ResponseDto > ) => {
                this.killTrigger.next();
                this.loading = false;
                this.showSearchResult(searchCriterias, response.body, actor, null);
            },
            (error: Error) => {
                this.loading = false;
                this.showSearchResult(searchCriterias, null, actor, error);
            }
        )
    },
    (error: Error) => {
        this.killTrigger.next();
        this.loading = false;
        this.showSearchResult(searchCriterias, null, actor, error);
    })
```

I believe this will answer your question.
Here, what I've done is took a timer observable named **refreshInterval** of 30000.
and **killTrigger** Subject.

Now your function call **this.searchService.search(search, this.taskId))** will be called every 30000. Until, you pass **killtrigger.next()**

Hope this solves your query.
I'm also learning rxjs so if anyone finds any easier or optimized way feel free to edit it.

Comment: Ok I will try this tomorrow, The original code polled each second and gave up after 30 seconds. I guess changing 30000 to pollingInterval will solve the poll delay. How do I add the give up after 30 secs!?

Comment: Yes, it'll run every 30 secs. The code for exiting is already there. **killtrigger.next()** in the success response will break the loop. Try and let me know

Comment: I haven't got this to work yet. I need a poling solution that inserts a delay between each poll. I tried the approach above but realized that the timer can fire off before the previous respond has come in.